# Customize formula in geom-smooth / ggplot2 / R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

I want to customize the formula used in geom_smooth like this:

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

data("Cars93", package = "MASS")

str(Cars93)

Cars93.log <- transform(Cars93, log.price = log(Price))

log.model <- lm(log.price ~ Horsepower*Origin, data = Cars93.log)
summary(log.model)
plot(log.model)

p <- ggplot(data = Cars93.log, aes(x = Horsepower, y = log.price, colour = Origin)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Origin, color = Origin)) +   # Punkte
  facet_grid(~ Origin) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(0,15,0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 7) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("USA" = "red","non-USA" = "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,16)) +
  ylab("Price(log)")

lm.mod <- function(df) {
  y ~ x*Cars93.log$Origin
}

p_smooth <- by(Cars93.log, Cars93.log$Origin, 
               function(x) geom_smooth(data=x, method = lm, formula = lm.mod(x)))

p + p_smooth
```

However, I receive the error that the computation failed because of different lengths of my used variables.

```
length(Cars93.log$log.price)
length(Cars93.log$Origin)
length(Cars93.log$Horsepower)
```

But when I check the length for each variable they're all the same... Any ideas, what's wrong?

Thanks a lot, Martina

Comment: You already are faceting by `Origin`, there is no need to include `Origin` in the formula, try `p + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x)`.

Comment: And the lengths *are* different: your custom function is getting only `x` corresponding to each facet and the entire vector `Cars93.log$Origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Rui Barradas, seems like the issue is the lines for `lm.mod` and `p_smooth` and the `by` function

Once you are making a distinction by Origin (e.g., by doing either `facet_wrap` or `color = Origin`) then `geom_smooth` will automatically run different models for those facets.

```
p <- ggplot(data = Cars93.log, 
            aes(x = Horsepower, y = log.price, color = Origin)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Origin)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Origin) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(0,15,0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 7) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("USA" = "red","non-USA" = "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,16)) +
  ylab("Price(log)")

p + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x)
```

you can convince yourself that this is the same as the output of `log.model` by extending the x-axis limits to see where the geom_smooth line would cross the y axis (e.g.,  `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 300))`)

You can also see the difference in the graph if you don't pass `color = Origin` to the `geom_smooth` function (essentially what is happening if you comment this out from the first ggplot() initialization):

```
p <- ggplot(data = Cars93.log, 
            aes(x = Horsepower, y = log.price)) + # color = Origin)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = Origin)) +
  #facet_wrap(~ Origin) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(0,15,0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 7) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("USA" = "red","non-USA" = "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,16)) +
  ylab("Price(log)")

p + geom_smooth(method = lm, formula = y ~ x)
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas, cmilando: thanks so much for your comments, now it's clear why I received this error. I have one question left: Is the interaction also incorporated by geom_smooth since it uses just the standard model y ~ x?

Comment: @Martina -- yes this interaction is incorporated by geom_smooth, as it creates two separate smoothed lines from each Origin. you can see what happens if you don't use either color = Origin or facet_wrap (~Origin) in the code I posted above